# Dependency and parameter to constructor

Tags: c#, dependencies, unity-container

I have:

```
[Dependency]
public qwe property { get; set; }
```

And:

```
class qwe
{
    public qwe()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("qwe");
    }

    public qwe(int x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("qwe INT");
    }  
}
```

How can I configure Unity so that when I have registered an int Unity creates my class qwe with the constructor that takes an int, but when I haven't registered an int value, Unity uses the constructor with zero parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either configure Unity to use the default constructor, the constructor that takes an integer parameter or declare a factory function that does that.

Default c'tor:

```
container.RegisterType<qwe>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

c'tor with integer parameter:

```
container.RegisterType<qwe>(new InjectionConstructor(myIntValue));
```

Factory:

```
container.RegisterType<qwe>(new InjectionFactory(c => (myIntValue > 0) ? new qwe(myIntValue) : new qwe()));
```